# Echo an Table field on the View

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

sorry my english is bad, but lets get going. Im trying to make an view to print one table field but i dont know how to do it, i tried some examples but not sucess.
Im calling the table field "descricao" from table "saidarecibo" leme show what im doing

on controller:

> public function imprecibosaidaAction() {
>
> ```
>   $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
>
>   $saidarecibo = $this->getTable('Admin\Model\Saidarecibo')->get($id);
>
>   if ($id == 0) {
>
>       throw new \Exception("Código obrigatório");
>
>   }
>
>    // Turn off the layout, i.e. only render the view script.
>    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
>    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
>    return $viewModel;
>
>    $view = new ViewModel(array(
>
>       'recibosaida' => $saidarecibo,
>
>
>
>   ));
>
>    return $view;
> ```
>
> }

and on the view:

```
<?php echo $saidarecibo['descricao']; ?>
<a style="margin-top:10px;" href="javascript:self.print()">IMPRIMIR</a>
```

Comment: In the view you use $saidarecibo variable but in the controller you pass to the view the variable recibosaida, so I guess you should use `<?php echo $recibosaida['descricao']; ?>`

Comment: Try $this->saidarecibo['descricao'];

Comment: I tried both of those on my view but nothing appears! just the IMPRIMIR button as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get your table correctly, I would do something like this:

On your view  imprecibosaida.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->saidarecibo; ?>
```

And on your controller imprecibosaidaAction(), after getting the table

```
$this->view->saidarecibo = $saidarecibo;
```

Anyway, I usually prefer to print my values one by one on the view, passing single values from the controller.
So I'd want to get $saidarecibo as an array of rows (you can just fetch a query in standard Zend DB adapters or paginators), and refer to it like this

In the view:

```
<table>

    <?php foreach $this->saidarecibo as $item 
          {?>
          <tr>
          <?php echo '<td>'. $this->item['descricao'] .'</td>';?>
          </tr>
          <?php 
          } ?>
</table>
```

And on the controller you get the values of the table, and as before

```
 $this->view->saidarecibo = $saidarecibo;
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Just tried it, but when i run my view it appears the error:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\wamp\www\Esa\module\Admin\src\Admin\Controller\SaidareciboController.php on line 262

Comment: (if you copy / pasted, i missed a character on the variable)... anyway, I guess that your array is empty. Add an if ($this->saidarecibo->count() ==0) { /*something happens */ }